# Can React app handle error (status code 4xx) with try catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch, react-hooks

I'm learning React (with hooks) and I encountered a weird issue. Im currently working on Notes Application (from FullStackOpen learn react). My database only accepts notes which content length is greater than 4 characters. In case of invalid note my server catches a ValidationError and returns an error message with status code 401 instead of new note. My goal is to catch this error in frontend and display an error message.

Backend code:

```
try{
    const savedNote = await note.save()
    user.notes = user.notes.concat(savedNote._id)
    await user.save()

    response.json(savedNote.toJSON())
  
  } catch(e) { 
    //console.log(e.name)
    const msg = {error: 'too short!!!'}
    //console.log(msg)
    return response.status(401).json(msg)
  }
```

Problem appears when I try to receive data at the front side of application. My development console displays *Error: Request failed with status code 401* no matter what I do. I can't find a way to enter *catch* block at front.

Frontend code for communication with server:

```
const create = async newObject => {
  const config = { headers: { Authorization: token } }
  const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, newObject, config)
  console.log(response.data)
  return response.data
}
```

(...)

```
const addNote = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try{      
      const noteObject = {
        content: newNote,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
        important: Math.random() > 0.5
      }

      noteService
        .create(noteObject)
          .then(returnedNote => {
            setNotes(notes.concat(returnedNote))
            setNewNote('')
            setErrorMsg('')
            setUserNotes(userNotes.concat(returnedNote))
      })    
    } catch (e) {///<----how to get there          
      setErrorMsg('note too short! minimum 5 characters')
      setNewNote('')
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMsg(null)
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
```

Some advices would be appreciated.

## Solution:

Chaining promises - *.catch()*

```
const addNote = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
      const noteObject = {
        content: newNote,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
        important: Math.random() > 0.5
      }

      noteService
        .create(noteObject)        
        .then(returnedNote => {
            setNotes(notes.concat(returnedNote))
            setNewNote('')
            setErrorMsg('')
            setUserNotes(userNotes.concat(returnedNote))
        })
        .catch(e => {
          setErrorMsg('note too short! minimum 5 characters')
          setNewNote('')
          setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorMsg(null)
          }, 5000)
        })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the try, catch block around your api call:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, newObject, config)
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

On another note, I don't recommend using **401** as the invalid status code as that has a reserved meaning of Unauthorized. Use **400** (Bad request) instead. The definitions of status codes: https://httpstatuses.com/

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I moved *create* function inside component and placed setters inside component. Is there any way to make that work in more neat way - with api call in separate "services" module? And error in dev console is still there, is that desired?

Comment: Yes, it's common to handle api calls in a separate file. Also 40X errors in console are fine. You may want to consider adding front end validation for a simple case like minimum character count.